# docker speeds up python, why?

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, docker

So I am playing with docker for the first time on my mac. I used `boot2docker` through the standard tutorial and I am starting a prompt in an ubuntu image.

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

When in docker I started my first experiment, to see if the performance would go down. From the command line I would use the python `timeit` module to quickly check some basic performance measures.

Mac Python Results

```
$ python3.4 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.7 usec per loop
$ python3.4 -m timeit '"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])'
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.2 usec per loop
$ python3.4 -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.2 usec per loop
```

Docker Python Results

```
> python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 30 usec per loop
> python3 -m timeit '"-".join([str(n) for n in range(100)])'
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.9 usec per loop
> python3 -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.2 usec per loop
```

It seems strange that the docker ubuntu, that is running on top of my mac, is actually running python code faster than the python on mac. Is there any reason for why this might be?

Edits

I can confirm that both python versions are running in 64 bit.

Mac Python

```
python3 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
7fffffffffffffff True
```

Ubuntu Python

```
python3.4 -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
7fffffffffffffff True
```

Comment: Are they both the same Python 3.x version?

Comment: ubuntu runs ```Python 3.4.0``` while mac runs ```Python 3.4.1``` if anything that might help explain why the mac should be quicker, no?

Comment: Is the Mac Python running as a 32-bit executable and the docker version a 64-bit executable? I've also seen compiler options make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: Can you run the experiment with a few different numbers of iterations in the loop, e.g. 1600, 4000, 10000, 25000?  That way you can try to see several things, for instance how much of the slowness is just constant overhead.

Comment: as you can see, even on three attempts, you have an almost 50% change in "performance". What does that means is that the computation to do is too small to be accurate. Try to have something that takes a least 1 second of computation time. And do the comparison again.

Comment: @YannSagon those are three different commands he is executing, having different cycles. My bet on this issue is that its simply totally different platforms, applying different libraries & resource management algorithms. In this specific case python seems to be running faster on linux.

Comment: There's no reason why docker'ed process should be fundamentally slower, esp. if cpu-bound. There is a case to drill down why it's faster though. Is it the difference between linux and osx runtime libraries? or is it the "nice" level at which process runs? something else?

Comment: "docker ubuntu, that is running on top of my mac", well, in fact, ubuntu is running beside your mac as VirtualBox is using Hardware-Assisted Virtualization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Hardware-assisted_virtualization Also, Docker does not slow processes as it is only a kernel trick to compartmentalize ressources.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Docker, same results on a standard Debian running inside VirtualBox on OS X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more about the difference in operating systems than about docker performance. Measuring performance of applications can be tricky.

Bottom line is that OS X has a good number of processes that will compete with your test and OS X likely did not give your test a high priority.

A container should perform as well as the native environment (sometimes better) in most cases. But, your test should make the container do work. Docker will need to add overhead when your application is making system calls and accessing I/O, so those should both be included in your test.

IBM wrote a paper on the Linux Container vs. Native env issue last year.

[http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf](http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf/)